# Issue with magento 1.9 config product import: "Product with specified super products SKU not found"

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import

I want to upload 100+ configurable products to Magento 1.9, I choose to import using CSV.

I had created one config product and its associated products manually, then I had exported that data and used the format for my import.

In the same format, when I am importing new SKUs, I am getting issues like this "Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows: 1, 2, 3
Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows: 2, 3"

When I skip that issue and import the data means, only associated simple products get imported. But, the configurable products do not get imported.

This is the CSV:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,name,description,short_description,price,special_price,special_from_date,special_to_date,cost,weight,manufacturer,meta_title,meta_keyword,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,media_gallery,color,news_from_date,news_to_date,gallery,status,url_key,url_path,minimal_price,visibility,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,options_container,required_options,has_options,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,created_at,updated_at,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp,tax_class_id,gift_message_available,slider,neck_type,sleeve_type,fabric,size,washing_ironing_instructions,size_new,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
Style-267-8,,Modesty,configurable,Women/Dresses/Casual Dresses/Her Modesty Style-101,Default Category,base,Style-267-8,,,500,,,,,,,,,,/2/7/2783_2.jpg,/2/7/2784_1.jpg,/2/7/2785_1.jpg,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8,Style-267-8.html,,4,,,,,,Product Info Column,1,1,,,,9/27/2016 12:56,9/27/2016 12:59,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2783_2.jpg,,1,0,Style-267-8-S,size_new,S,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2784_1.jpg,,3,0,Style-267-8-L,size_new,L,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2785_1.jpg,,4,0,Style-267-8-M,size_new,M,
Style-267-8-S,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-S,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-s,Style-267-8-s.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:56,9/27/2016 12:56,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,S,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Style-267-8-L,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-L,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-l,Style-267-8-l.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:57,9/27/2016 12:57,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,L,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Style-267-8-M,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-M,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-m,Style-267-8-m.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:57,9/27/2016 12:57,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,M,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

[View in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c2ld6uwcy6f0tg/catalog_product_20160928_054239.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow below steps:

1. Create the simple product rows
2. Create configurable product row
3. Assign child products to the configurable product

Below is the very basic csv sample;

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,color,cost,description,meta_keyword,name,price,short_description,size,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
F0000077.03,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,3,,,,
F0000077.04,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,4,,,,
F0000077.05,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,5,,,,
F0000077.06,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,6,,,,
F0000077.07,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,7,,,,
F0000077.08,default,Default,simple,High Heels,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,8,,,,
F0000077,default,Default,configurable,New In,Default Category,base,Black,10.99,Product description,"New in, heels, heeled sandals",Product name,25,Product Shot description here,,F0000077.03,size,3,0
,,,,High Heels,Default Category,,,,,,,,,,F0000077.04,size,4,0
,,,,High Heels/Heeled Sandals,Default Category,,,,,,,,,,F0000077.05,size,5,0
,,,,High Heels/Strappy Heels,Default Category,,,,,,,,,,F0000077.06,size,6,0
,,,,Sandals,Default Category,,,,,,,,,,F0000077.07,size,7,0
,,,,High Heels,Default Category,,,,,,,,,,F0000077.08,size,8,0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's working good. I am having another one issue. unable to map my images in import process. Please check with the sample file and Image url please.                                                                                 Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqsb8uxjriidqui/catalog_product_20160928_134010.csv?dl=0                                                                                                                    Image URL: http://mastoraretail.com/media/catalog/product/1458110863-1.JPG      Please check and update the right way to update.

Comment: Did you copy the images to media/import/?

Answer (score 0):

The import goes through the file line by line:

1. create configurable product
2. associate simple products
3. create simple products

This won't work because the simple products do not exist yet at step 2. **Solution:** reorder the lines, simple products first:

```
sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,name,description,short_description,price,special_price,special_from_date,special_to_date,cost,weight,manufacturer,meta_title,meta_keyword,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,media_gallery,color,news_from_date,news_to_date,gallery,status,url_key,url_path,minimal_price,visibility,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,options_container,required_options,has_options,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,created_at,updated_at,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,msrp,tax_class_id,gift_message_available,slider,neck_type,sleeve_type,fabric,size,washing_ironing_instructions,size_new,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,_links_related_sku,_links_related_position,_links_crosssell_sku,_links_crosssell_position,_links_upsell_sku,_links_upsell_position,_associated_sku,_associated_default_qty,_associated_position,_tier_price_website,_tier_price_customer_group,_tier_price_qty,_tier_price_price,_group_price_website,_group_price_customer_group,_group_price_price,_media_attribute_id,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
Style-267-8-S,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-S,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-s,Style-267-8-s.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:56,9/27/2016 12:56,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,S,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Style-267-8-L,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-L,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-l,Style-267-8-l.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:57,9/27/2016 12:57,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,L,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Style-267-8-M,,Modesty,simple,,,base,Style-267-8-M,,,500,,,,,,,,,,,,,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8-m,Style-267-8-m.html,,1,,,,,,Product Info Column,0,0,,,,9/27/2016 12:57,9/27/2016 12:57,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,M,1000,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Style-267-8,,Modesty,configurable,Women/Dresses/Casual Dresses/Her Modesty Style-101,Default Category,base,Style-267-8,,,500,,,,,,,,,,/2/7/2783_2.jpg,/2/7/2784_1.jpg,/2/7/2785_1.jpg,,grey,,,,1,Style-267-8,Style-267-8.html,,4,,,,,,Product Info Column,1,1,,,,9/27/2016 12:56,9/27/2016 12:59,,Use config,Use config,,0,,No,Crew,Elbow,Ramie,,WASHING AND IRONING INSRUCTIONS - WHEN YOU WASH 1. Wash below 40 degrees C. 2. Do not use excessive detergent 3. Do not use any detergent which contains bleach or liquid bleach 4. Rinse thoroughly,,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2783_2.jpg,,1,0,Style-267-8-S,size_new,S,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2784_1.jpg,,3,0,Style-267-8-L,size_new,L,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,88,/2/7/2785_1.jpg,,4,0,Style-267-8-M,size_new,M,
```

Importing the file twice might work too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's working good. I am having another one issue. unable to map my images in import process. Please check with the sample file and Image url please.                                                                                 Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqsb8uxjriidqui/catalog_product_20160928_134010.csv?dl=0                                                                                                                    Image URL: http://mastoraretail.com/media/catalog/product/1458110863-1.JPG      Please check and update the right way to update.

Comment: If you have a different problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Please check this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138505/how-to-map-the-images-with-magento-product-import-process-by-csv/138506#138506

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your csv, there is a mistake in csv data.

As per you csv data there is a configurable product is first and after simple product data.

but as per magento csv data when you import configurable product, first row must be simple product and then add configurable data.

Try this solution and let me know if not working.