# How to map the images with magento product import process by csv

Tags: magento-1.9, import, product-images

When i am updating the products using csv import in magento, i am having  one issue. unable to map my images in import process. Please check with the sample file and Image url please.                                                                                 Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqsb8uxjriidqui/catalog_product_20160928_134010.csv?dl=0                                                                                                                    Image URL: http://mastoraretail.com/media/catalog/product/1458110863-1.JPG      Please check and update the right way to update.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy your images to media/import directory of magento and specify that path:

For example if your image is **media/import/product/1458110863.JPG**, you need to add **"product/1458110863.JPG"** to your csv file. Magento will take care of copying the image to the right path and assigning it to the product

Comment: I had checked with this format, no use. still image not mapped with import product.

Comment: Can you share your updated csv?